# Modified Pólya-Eggenberger Urn Problem

Tags: statistics

An urn contains $0$ black balls and $n$ white balls. $k$ balls are picked up at random and replaced by $k$ black balls. This process repeats itself till all the balls in the urn are black.

What is the expected number of black balls in the urn after $j$ steps of picking up?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on one ball. The chance that it has not been replaced after $j$ trials is $(1-{k\over n})^j$. The chance that it has been replaced is $1-(1-{k\over n})^j$, and so the expected number of replaced (black) balls after $j$ trials is 
$$n\left(1-\left(1-{k\over n}\right)^j\right).$$

This problem is very similar to [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105430/dice-problem-numerical-approximation/)